# How to create SharePoint list item with Microsoft Graph API?

Tags: sharepoint, microsoft-graph-api

I am trying to create list items with Microsoft Graph API to a SharePoint endpoint. My URL is as follows:

```
https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/sites/{id}.sharepoint.com:/sites/{name of the site}:/lists/{list_id}/items
```

Calling this URL with POST, and a body like this:

```
{
    "fields": {
        "FileLeafRef": "757391.pdf",
        "ContentType": "Document",
        "Application_x0020_Name": "ABC",
    }
}
```

It is giving error as

> "message": "Files and folders should only be added to a
>   DocumentLibrary via the OneDrive API"

Can some one help on this, how to fix this issue?

Here I am trying to create metadata for document, with in a list.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You cannot upload a file (i.e. create a *new* ListItem in a Document Library) like that. You will need to first upload the file using the [OneDrive endpoints](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/docs/api-reference/v1.0/api/driveitem_put_content):

```
PUT /v1.0/sites/{site-id}/drive/items/{parent-id}:/{filename}:/content
POST /v1.0/sites/{siteId}/drive/items/{driveItem-id}/createUploadSession
```

Once you have the file in the document library, you can then update the metadata on the existing file using the [SharePoint endpoints](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/docs/api-reference/v1.0/api/listitem_update):

```
PATCH h/v1.0/sites/{site-id}/lists/{list-id}/items/{listItem-id}/fields

{
    "FileLeafRef": "757391.pdf",
    "ContentType": "Document",
    "Application_x0020_Name": "ABC"
}
```

Comment: Thanks you @Marc it's working. Only one problem I am facing while updating the fields. It is getting updated successfully in sharePoint. But is response I am getting this error:  `"message": "The MIME type &#39;text/html, image/gif, image/jpeg, *; q=.2, */*; q=.2&#39; requires a &#39;/&#39; character between type and subtype, such as &#39;text/plain&#39;.",`

Comment: GOT IT: **Accept** was missing after adding accept it is working now

Comment: Thank you @Marc it's working for me. However, my concern is how to retrieve {listItem-id} from OneDrive endpoint when we first using PUT request?

Comment: @amzdmt i found it. You can add /listItem at the end of driveitem graph url and send a get request to fetch listitem information.